# How to shuffle the outer index randomly but the order the inner index in ascending order in a multi index dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index, shuffle

The following piece of code generates a sample dataframe:

```
fruits=pd.DataFrame()
fruits['month']=['jan','feb','feb','march','jan','april','april','june','march','march','june','april']
fruits['fruit']=['apple','orange','pear','orange','apple','pear','cherry','pear','orange','cherry','apple','cherry']
ind_mnth=fruits['month'].values
ind_fruit=fruits['fruit'].values
fruits['price']=[30,20,40,25,30 ,45,60,45,25,55,37,60]
fruits_grp = fruits.set_index([ind_mnth, ind_fruit],drop=False)
```

How can I shuffle the outer index randomly and inner index in ascending order in this multi-index data frame?

Comment: so fruit column is dependent on index for sorting?

Comment: yes, the fruit column depends on the month.

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this:

```
mnths = fruits.drop_duplicates(subset=['month']).sample(frac=1).reset_index().month.unique()
fruits.groupby(['month','fruit'])['price'].sum().loc[mnths]
```

first you pick a random sorting of the months in the dataframe, then groupby month and fruit, which will sort alphabetically, then index using the randomly ordered months list

Comment: The prices are getting summed/added. This should not be the case.

Comment: they're only summed if there are duplicate month and fruit combinations.  Assuming there are no duplicate rows, this won't be an issue

Comment: with the assumption that there are duplicate month and fruit rows in the dataset, the prices are not to be summed